# asking for information to my sql database with node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database

I am following a tutorial of how to connect my app to mysql database, but at this point, my program does not work out as it used to be.

this is the function to select the rows from jugadores and render it on the view

```
const router = express.Router();    
const pool = mysql.createPool


router.get('/', async(req, res) => {
    const jugadores = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM jugadores');
    console.log(jugadores)
    res.render('jugadores/list', { jugadores: jugadores })
});
```

the console show this:

```
Query {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _callback: undefined,
  _callSite: Error
      at Pool.query (C:\Users\Jehan\Desktop\Proyecto_chess\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:199:23)
      at C:\Users\Jehan\Desktop\Proyecto_chess\src\routes\jugadores.js:24:34
      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Jehan\Desktop\Proyecto_chess\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
      at next (C:\Users\Jehan\Desktop\Proyecto_chess\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
      at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Jehan\Desktop\Proyecto_chess\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Jehan\Desktop\Proyecto_chess\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
      at C:\Users\Jehan\Desktop\Proyecto_chess\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
      at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Jehan\Desktop\Proyecto_chess\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
      at next (C:\Users\Jehan\Desktop\Proyecto_chess\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
      at Function.handle (C:\Users\Jehan\Desktop\Proyecto_chess\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3),
  _ended: false,
  _timeout: undefined,
  _timer: Timer { _object: [Circular], _timeout: null },
  sql: 'SELECT * FROM jugadores',
  values: undefined,
  typeCast: true,
  nestTables: false,
  _resultSet: null,
  _results: [],
  _fields: [],
  _index: 0,
  _loadError: null
}
```

how can I do to show the jugadores variables?
PD: the tutorial shows how this console.log give it back the rows of the table jugadores in the database

Comment: You need to call `.createPool(...)`, as explained [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections)

Comment: `pool.query('SELECT * FROM jugadores', function(error, rows, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].jugadores);
});`
createPool require ('./database') and the database is in the file database.js
i use this function and it return undefined

Comment: Can you link us to the tutorial you're following? Also, if you have made changes to your code and it still doesn't work, please update your question accordingly.